# How to get all chat members in telegram using telebot api?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

English it's not my native language

So I trying to make telegram bot that mention all users in group when u use command `/call`, but I don't know how to get id's of all group users

I tried this code

```
input: chat_id = message.chat.id
       members = bot.get_chat_members(chat_id)

output: AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'get_chat_members'
```

and this code

```
input: chat_id = message.chat.id
       count = bot.get_chat_members_count(chat_id)

output: telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: invalid user_id specified
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Telegram's official documentation bots can not get the complete list of all group participants. As you can see [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember) bots only can get the list of Administrators and the count of group users.
However, you can listen to all new message events in the group and save senders' information to your database for later use.